# Go to implementation doesn't work for Python in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: python, intellij-idea

[Image link of directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1egZi.png)Nothing happens if I press Ctrl+Alt+B in my python project on IntelliJIdea and it feels as if this feature is not supported for Python in IntelliJ, from whatever I read, PyCharm has this feature, and considering both are from JetBrains, I fail to understand how that is not working.

Same for library method options, I've installed scikit-learn in my conda environment but when I press control+space after scikit-learn. I don't see any suggestions coming my way. I need solution to both these issues, if IntelliJ does support both these features for python or I've to go to pyCharm which is kind of a let down honestly.

Comment: Why don't you use PyCharm? it's jetbrains IDE similar to IntelliJ, but Python oriented.

Comment: Did you actually install the Python plugin? All these features are supported in the Python plugin. If they don't work for you, please provide more information on how your project is configured.

Comment: I have python plugin installed for intelliJ, but it's not working properly. Doesn't detect modules or anything and nor does it provide suggestions.

Comment: Have you configured a Project Interpreter?
If yes, make sure you are using the correct shortcut - check Keymap settings.

Comment: How is your project configured? Are your Python files under a source root of a module? Does the module have a Python facet?

Comment: @yole I'm using a conda environment as python interpreter and the python plugin is installed. All the packages are there, the syntax highlighting is working fine but the code completion isn't

Comment: Yes there's a root module and has __init__.py and it has many modules along inside all with __init__.py files inside em

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of your IDE with the project view and editor visible.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1egZi.png

Comment: The code suggest is working for libraries now, I've fixed that by adding sdk path to global settings, but the go to implementation is not working for internal modules I've written.